# MySQL - Get delta from timeseries data without consecutive IDs

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL (v5.7) table that lists total bytes downloaded (rx) and uploaded (tx), with a new row added very several minutes. It looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `vsz_port_usage` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `port_id` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `switch_id` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `tx` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rx` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16508 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

A sample of the data from this table is provided below:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM wngateway.vsz_port_usage WHERE port_id = "38:45:3b:31:de:c3" AND switch_id = "38:45:3B:31:DE:C0";
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------------+
| id    | port_id           | switch_id         | tx            | rx            | timestamp           |
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------------+
|     4 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3126866259074 | 2727524584234 | 2023-03-28 16:55:15 |
|   574 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3126949814406 | 2727608850120 | 2023-03-28 17:02:56 |
|  1084 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3127116537385 | 2727671060330 | 2023-03-28 17:10:35 |
|  1654 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3127161454192 | 2727730825273 | 2023-03-28 17:18:12 |
|  2224 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3127209850150 | 2727789725082 | 2023-03-28 17:25:44 |
|  2794 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3127261843354 | 2727857810107 | 2023-03-28 17:33:13 |
|  3364 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3127505346539 | 2727924253856 | 2023-03-28 17:40:45 |
|  3874 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3127552181876 | 2727996539653 | 2023-03-28 17:48:10 |
|  4414 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3127596719416 | 2728093456168 | 2023-03-28 17:55:35 |
|  4924 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3127633796826 | 2728150420149 | 2023-03-28 18:02:57 |
|  5464 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3127670877957 | 2728209622767 | 2023-03-28 18:10:17 |
|  6034 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3127706937042 | 2728261806883 | 2023-03-28 18:17:37 |
|  6604 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3127741830389 | 2728314163774 | 2023-03-28 18:24:56 |
|  6978 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3127880878103 | 2728520542559 | 2023-03-28 18:52:09 |
|  7548 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3127918304029 | 2728574025851 | 2023-03-28 18:59:29 |
|  8118 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3127955080807 | 2728629520073 | 2023-03-28 19:06:47 |
|  8688 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3127989942390 | 2728674438455 | 2023-03-28 19:14:05 |
|  9228 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3128025603126 | 2728727026310 | 2023-03-28 19:21:24 |
| 10188 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3128090879265 | 2728823583786 | 2023-03-28 19:34:02 |
| 10758 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3128126820925 | 2728877792466 | 2023-03-28 19:41:22 |
| 11298 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3128162508736 | 2728936652870 | 2023-03-28 19:48:40 |
| 11868 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3128207015787 | 2728990048376 | 2023-03-28 19:55:58 |
| 12438 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3128242657007 | 2729044410663 | 2023-03-28 20:03:17 |
| 12978 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3128281289362 | 2729095897374 | 2023-03-28 20:10:35 |
| 13816 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3128768754738 | 2729637994066 | 2023-03-28 21:21:39 |
| 14416 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3128804556717 | 2729700885692 | 2023-03-28 23:42:05 |
| 14926 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3128840388617 | 2729744850403 | 2023-03-29 01:57:23 |
| 15496 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3128941449996 | 2729796746975 | 2023-03-29 04:13:59 |
| 16065 | 38:45:3b:31:de:c3 | 38:45:3B:31:DE:C0 | 3128977421603 | 2729854403640 | 2023-03-29 06:30:37 |
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

The tx and rx values are the total at that given timestamp. I need to access the data in such a way that it can be graphed over time, i.e. the rx and tx values should be calculated as tx[n] - tx[n-1].

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11372271/4933165) was promising, however the difference here is my table contains multiple different series, differentiated by the combination of switch_id and port_id column values. This means that I can't just use the autoincrement id column minus one to do the delta calculations.

Here's what I've tried to do as a workaround, but the join returns no rows, presumably because of the way I am artificially creating the rownumber in the queries.

```
SELECT 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, m1.timestamp, m2.timestamp) AS diff_timestamp,
    m2.rx - m1.rx AS diff_rx
FROM ( SELECT 
            @rownum:=@rownum+1 as id,
            tx, rx, timestamp 
        FROM wngateway.vsz_port_usage
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS row_counts
        WHERE port_id = "38:45:3b:31:de:c3" AND switch_id = "38:45:3B:31:DE:C0") AS m1
JOIN ( SELECT 
            @rownum:=@rownum+1 as id,
            tx, rx, timestamp 
        FROM wngateway.vsz_port_usage
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS row_counts
        WHERE port_id = "38:45:3b:31:de:c3" AND switch_id = "38:45:3B:31:DE:C0") AS m2
ON (m1.id = m2.id-1)
```

Is what I want to do possible using purely MySQL?

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0? Window functions are the best solution for this task, but it requires 8.0. Check the version: `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: I am unfortunately currently limited to MySQL v5.7, I'll add this to the main question.

Comment: Okay someday when you upgrade to 8.0, you can use window functions for this. By the way, 5.7 is due to reach end of support in October 2023, so you should be thinking about upgrading to 8.0 anyway.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll see if I can upgrade our server and test if there are any breaking changes. Is there any chance you could outline how the above can be done using window functions?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a solution using [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) in MySQL 8.0:

```
SELECT
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, LAG(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY id), timestamp) AS diff_timestamp,
  rx - LAG(rx) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS diff_rx
FROM vsz_port_usage;
```

[DbFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/4mlcmy7_)

Comment: Thank you, I'll spin up a v8.0 database and try this.